# ElastAlert combining query and range into an OR clause

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, kibana, elastalert

I have a kibana query to find all transactions which are either having result "HTTP 5xx" or a response code greater than equal to 400

```
service.name : "my-service" AND transaction.name : "my-transaction" AND (transaction.result: "HTTP 5xx" OR http.response.status_code >= 400)
```

I need to use this same query in ElastAlert Rule (.yaml file). I can use status code in `range` and which will play as AND clause with query, but how I could I use `transaction.result` below:

```
filter:
- query:
   query_string:
    query: 'service.name : "my-service" AND transaction.name : "my-transaction"'
- range:
    http.response.status_code:
      gt: 399
```

Can anyone help how to include this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`and` and `or`](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/writing_filters.html#negation-and-or) in your filter definitions:

```
filter:
  - and:
      - query:
          query_string:
            query: >-
              service.name : "my-service" AND transaction.name :
              "my-transaction"
      - or:
          - term:
              transaction.result: HTTP 5xx
          - range:
              http.response.status_code:
                gt: 399
```

Or you can also get rid of the `query_string` query and spell it out into individual queries:

```
filter:
  - and:
      - term:
          service.name: my-service
      - term:
          transaction.name: my-transaction
      - or:
          - term:
              transaction.result: HTTP 5xx
          - range:
              http.response.status_code:
                gt: 399
```

Comment: Thank you, I am gonna test this before marking it accepted. I feel indentation issue with first one, let me test that out. :)

Comment: Yeah, YAML sucks big time :-) I fixed the indenting. Let me know